# Sharing common constants and log function in separate files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, constants

What are my options for sharing constants between different files with the same NodeJS project?

I'm following,
https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3bo42p/sharing_constants_in_es6_modules/

```
$ cat  constants.js
const ALABAMA  = 1;
const ALASKA = 3;
const ARIZONA =4;
```

**UPDATE**, *Other details removed as it is not a good example for me to follow for my specific question*.

Also, along the same line,

I want to have the common log facility using this package, 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/brolog

However, I found initializing it in `index.js` file is not enough for all other files to use it.

```
const brolog = require('brolog')
const log = new brolog.Brolog()

const logLevel = process.env['MY_LOG']

if (logLevel) {
  log.level(logLevel)
  log.verbose('Config', 'Log Level set to %s', logLevel, log.level())
}
```

I don't want to repeat all above setup among all my NodeJS files.

So, how to sharing common constants and log functionality between different files within the same NodeJS project?

PS. This is only a small & simple project, and I don't want to pull-in/use big npm modules like commonJS just for this.

Comment: Node doesn't support `import` and `export` syntax (from ES6 modules) by default yet. If you're using Node 10, you can rename your file to have the extension `mjs` and execute via `node foobar.mjs --experimental-modules`.

Comment: @Jankapunkt No, the OP is correct.

Comment: OK. Let me remove ES6 modules from the question as focus on JS instead then... and ... _UPDATED_.

Comment: @xpt Maybe use a singleton for `brolog`? i.e. have one file that creates an instance of the logger, then exports it so that you can import it everywhere and use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [globals](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/globals.html#globals_global) to share objects and constants across an entire NodeJS project.

**`constants.js`**

```
const brolog = require("brolog");
global.log = new brolog.Brolog();
global.logLevel = process.env['MY_LOG'];
```

**`index.js`**

```
require("./constants");
require("./other");
```

**`other.js`**

```
if (logLevel) {
    log.level(logLevel)
    log.verbose('Config', 'Log Level set to %s', logLevel, log.level())
}
```

---

#### Footnote

This approach can cause problems, as it pollutes the global namespace. It *is* one of the simplest approaches to solve your problem, but it's worth creating global constants in this way *as sparingly as possible*. It makes your code harder to test, maintain, reuse, and generally reason about. As long as you know what you're doing, you'll be fine!

Comment: that looks good but could you give one more sample code on how to make use of my `const log` as well please?

Comment: Sure, one second! :)

Comment: Perfect. THX! This requires minimum change to my existing code, when splitting from `index.js` to other files. I'm aware of the global namespace pollution problem, so I'm only use it for global constants and unified logging.

Comment: By the way, you can use this in earlier version of node. I've changed the link to use node 6> but it works all the way back to the very first version of node (0.10)! https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/globals.html#globals_global

Comment: @xpt - Except perhaps for some cases involving logging, globals is generally a BAD solution and we should not be teaching it here.  The price of good modularity is a little bit more boilerplate at the start of your module to properly import the things you need.  Get used to it.  It's the right way to code in node.js.

Comment: Logging is exactly the purpose @xpt is using it for. I agree (and have said) that it's generally a bad solution, but I disagree strongly with your assertion we should avoid teaching it here because of that. We should be teaching it _exactly_ here, as long as we're also warning of the problems (which I believe we are).

Answer (score 6):

A common pattern for your app-wide constants and utility functions in Node.js is to create a module for them, instantiate/setup whatever you need and use that module where you need, e.g.:

**common.js**:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  /**
   * The const of Alabama.
   *
   * @const {number}
   */
  ALABAMA: 1,

  /**
   * The const of Alaska.
   *
   * @const {number}
   */
  ALASKA: 3,

  /**
   * The const of Arizona.
   *
   * @const {number}
   */
  ARIZONA: 4,

  logLevel: process.env['MY_LOG'],
  log: new brolog.Brolog()
}
```

Then `require` it wherever you need to use a common constant and/or utility function or class:

**app.js**:

```
const common = require('common')

if (common.logLevel) {
  common.log.level(common.logLevel)
  common.log.verbose('Config', 'Log Level set to %s', common.logLevel, common.log.level())
}
```

---

And of course you can and it's commonly encouraged to simplify your utility functions to make them more convenient to use *(but no simpler, than necessary)*:

more customized **common.js**:

```
'use strict'

const logger = new brolog.Brolog()

module.exports = {
  /*
   ... constants ...
  */

  // more describing
  isLogging: process.env['MY_LOG'],

  // shorthand for leveling
  level: common.log.level,

  // shorthand for verbose logging
  verbose: common.log.verbose,

  // shorthand for warn logging
  warn: common.log.warn,

  // shorthand for error logging
  error: common.log.error
}
```

using in **app.js**:

```
const common = require('common')

if (common.isLogging) {
  common.verbose('...')
  common.warn('...')
  common.error('...')
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Good for people using NodeJS < ver 10. Upvoting.

Comment: Also giving you a +1, great answer! This pattern is the way you _should_ do it if you can!

Comment: Yeah, Agree @SamHolmes. I think I'd better do this even I have Node10, and a little bit more complicated (in steps) than using globals.

Comment: Just to say, my globals solution works in much _much_ earlier versions of node than 10 (all the way down to 0.10!) It's one of the first features ever implemented! https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/globals.html#globals_global

Comment: @xpt - This is the proper modular way of doing things in node.js.  Do not use globals.  Your code is more testable, more reusable, more maintainable, etc... when you avoid using globals.  Get used to a little more boilerplate at the start of your modules to properly import that things you need.  It's a small cost to get all the benefits of modularity.

Comment: Thanks @SamHolmes, I return the gesture. ;)